# ReactiveUI: View does not contain a definition for 'WhenActivated'

Tags: reactiveui

I am getting the following error `'MachineLayoutView' does not contain a definition for 'WhenActivated' and the best extension method overload 'ViewForMixins.WhenActivated(ISupportsActivation, Func<IEnumerable<IDisposable>>)' requires a receiver of type 'ISupportsActivation'` On the `this.WhenActivated` line of the View constructor

As far as I can tell I am following the [Getting Started](https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/) correctly.

Note: I am using WPF and I have my ViewModels in a separate assembly/project that is referenced by the Views Project. (Not sure if that matters or not)

View

```
using RAL.RealTime.ViewModel;
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RAL.RealTime
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MachineLayoutView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MachineLayoutView : ReactiveUserControl<MachineLayoutViewModel>
    {
        public MachineLayoutView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration =>
            {
                this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel,
                                    viewModel => viewModel.MachineStatuses,
                                    view => view.MachineStatuses)
                                    .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using RAL.Repository;
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace RAL.RealTime.ViewModel
{
    public class MachineLayoutViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IEnumerable<MachineStatusViewModel>> _machineStatuses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<MachineStatusViewModel> MachineStatuses => _machineStatuses.Value;

    }
}
```

EDIT:

Per Glenn Watson's suggestion, I have tried the following with no change.

```
public MachineLayoutView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration =>
    {
        disposable(this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                            viewModel => viewModel.MachineStatuses,
                            view => view.MachineStatuses));

    });

}
```

Comment: There are two WhenActivated methods, one using the interface `IActivatable` which is for views, another for `ISupportsActivation` which is for view models. `ReactiveUserControl<T>` derives off `IActivatable` which shouldn't be a problem here (`IViewFor<T>` also derives off `IActivatable`). Try the version where you call it like a method, eg `disposable(this.OneWayBind(....));` and see if that helps.

Comment: I have now tried it, no change. same error. I updated my Question to reflect that I have now tried this.

Comment: @GlennWatson any thoughts?

Comment: on the ViewModel change ISupportsActivation to IActivatableViewModel,  I experimented on https://github.com/TheEightBot/Reactive-Examples

Answer (score 0):

Is this a compile time or run time error?  If it's compile time.  Make sure that the XAML (assuming there is XAML) has the correct namespace and that view control is the same type as the inherited type in the. i.e. `UserControl` should read `ReactiveUserControl` in the XAML script.

snagged from the getting started:

```xml
<reactiveui:ReactiveUserControl
  x:Class="ReactiveDemo.NugetDetailsView"
  xmlns:reactiveDemo="clr-namespace:ReactiveDemo"
  x:TypeArguments="reactiveDemo:NugetDetailsViewModel"
  xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image x:Name="iconImage" Margin="6" Width="64" Height="64"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
                 Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <Run FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" x:Name="titleRun"/>
          <LineBreak />
          <Run FontSize="12" x:Name="descriptionRun"/>
          <LineBreak />
          <Hyperlink x:Name="openButton">Open</Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</reactiveui:ReactiveUserControl>
```